# Prove that every topology in X is a basis for itself.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Here's my proof:

Let $\mathcal{T}$ be a topology and $x \in X$. Since $\mathcal{T}$ is a topology on $X$, then $x \in X \in \mathcal {T} \Rightarrow  X \subset \bigcup B_x \Rightarrow X = \bigcup B_x$, $(B_x \subset \mathcal{T})$.

Let $B_1, B_2$ in $\mathcal{T} \Rightarrow B_1 \cap B_2 \in \mathcal{T}$

Let $x \in B_1 \cap B_2$ and $B_3 = B_1 \cap B_2$, then $x \in B_3 \subset B_1 \cap B_2$. Then $\mathcal{T}$ is a basis.

Now we prove $\mathcal{T}$ is a basis for itself:

If $U \in \mathcal{T}$, then for each $x \in U$,$ x\ \in U \subset U$, which shows that $\mathcal{T}$ is generated by $\mathcal{T}$.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: What exactly is your question?

Comment: I want to ask about my proof whether it's correct or not

Comment: The last line of the proof doesn't make sense. May be there is a typo. What does $U\in U$ mean?

Comment: Thank you. I just fixed it!

Comment: Furthermore, in your 2nd and 3rd paragraphs you have $\subset \mathcal{T}$ when you should have $\in \mathcal{T}$.

Answer (score 0):

The proof that $\mathcal{T}$ is a base for some topology (which is what you checked) is essentially correct (the topology contains $X$ and is closed under intersections).

You showed that every $U \in \mathcal{T}$ is indeed open for the topology generated by the base (which is quite trivial). You omit to show why there are no more open sets than those already in $\mathcal{T}$, so the proof is incomplete as it stands.

Alternatively, a base for $\mathcal{T}$ (so starting with a topology) is (by definiton!) a subset $\mathcal{B}$ of $\mathcal{T}$ so that every open set in $\mathcal{T}$ can be written as a union of members from $\mathcal{B}$. And clearly we can write every $O \in \mathcal{T}$ as a union of the one set family $\{O\}$, so taking $\mathcal{B} = \mathcal{T}$ is one option.

So with one proof you start with a collection of subsets, check that its unions generate a topology and check this is the original one. My alternative starts with a topology and checks that a subset of it (in this case all of it) generates it (by unions).